# Detect raspberry pi on google home

Tags: raspberry-pi3, google-assistant-sdk, google-home

I implemented Google assistant on Raspberry PI using Google Assistant Library.
And, I would like to connect my Raspberry PI to Google Home.
(Want to detect Raspberry PI on Google Home App)

1)
On google assistant, I could find Raspberry PI on device lists.
But it is not detectable on Google home app, even I had registered raspberry Pi in my google account.

2) 
Google Assistant -> more settings -> Home control in Services tab.
When I clicked above path, I could see raspberry Pi with No room assigned status. So, I tried to change Nickname and Room for pi.
But the error message occured(Couldn't update the setting.Check your connection.)

Do I have to do something else for these things?
Is there any possible way for these?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The integration between the Google Home and devices with the Google Assistant library is not very deep, such that the Google Home will not recognize any Raspberry Pis on the network.

Both devices are connected to your Google account, such that personal queries will return the same response on both devices.

Google Assistant SDK devices currently don't get a room assignment. There isn't any reason to put it in the HomeGraph as things like room control and remote execution are currently not supported.